# obtaining regression coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I have plotted the scatter plot below using the following scripts but still need to obtain the regression coefficient.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
lm.irt12 <- lm(prtemp ~ irt12,data=apirt)
summary(lm.irt12)
plot(apirt$irt12[apirt$surv==1],
     apirt$prtemp[apirt$surv==1],
     xlab="ave. base of ears (°C)",
     ylab="rectal (°C)",
     xlim=c(26,42),
     ylim=c(30,42),
     col='blue')
points(apirt$irt12[apirt$surv==0], apirt$prtemp[apirt$surv==0],col='red')
abline(lm.irt12)
abline(h=36,v=0, col="gray10",lty=20)
#col = "gray60" OR col = "lightgray", lty=3; #(lty=3: broken line, 1:continuous)
text(26.7,36.7,parse(text='36*degree'),col='gray10')
abline(h=34,v=0, col="gray10",lty=20)
#col = "gray60" OR col = "lightgray", lty=3; #(lty=3: broken line, 1:continuous)
text(26.7,34.7,parse(text='34.0*degree'),col='gray10')
```

[image]

Comment: Your second line of code should return the coefficients. Also, `coef(lm.irt12)`.

Comment: @jbaums: many thanks for your help! You are right, summary(lm.irt12) gave me the same coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to get the `coefficient` parameter of your linear model object `lm.irt12`:

```
lm.irt12$coefficients
```

To see the parameter of R objects, you can do:

```
str(lm.irt12)
```